# Как конвертировать в pdf фаил кирилическими символами в PhpWord?

Tags: php, phpword

вот код как я делаю.

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($fileName);
        $lang = new Language();
        $lang->setLangId(1049);
        $phpWord->getSettings()->setThemeFontLang($lang);
        Settings::setPdfRendererPath(dirname(__DIR__).'/../vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
        Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
        $writer = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord,'PDF');
        header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="downloaded.pdf"');
        $writer->save('php://output');
```

получаю в место
`тест` получаю `????` вопрос что я делаю не так

Comment: Когда я работал с этой библиотекой у меня была такая же проблема.
Вам необходимо подключить шрифт, который поддерживает весь UTF-8, по умолчанию в PhpWord используется шрифт без UTF-8. Так же необходимо установить кодировку файла на UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

В обшем итоге как я понял проблема была в DomPDF перешел на mPdf русские символы отображаются.

Comment: Лучше внести правку в вопрос, или вообще удалить вопрос. Т.к. данный ответ не решает проблемы от слова совсем.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ну... Так-то, если задача - именно результат получить, а не получить результат силами строго определённой библиотеки - то вполне себе ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Задача - пофиксить работу с PhpWord. Когда люди придут из поисковика и увидят "а удалите PhpWord и воспользуйтесь mPdf" - ну, такое.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это да, но, с другой стороны, они, как и ТС, увидят вариант решения проблемы в смене библиотеки. Если для ТС такое решение подошло - то может и другим подойти)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб может вы и правы. Интересно бы послушать, что другие скажут, как в будущем с такими ответами поступать. На мете чуть позже вопрос задам.

Comment: @Suvitruf
Он находит временое решение пока не решать разработчики. В vendor как то не особо хочется

Answer (score 0):

1. убелиться что подключен `mpdf/mpdf`, если нет то:

`composer require mpdf/mpdf`

2. указать следующую настройку

`Settings::setPdfRendererName(Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF);`